# Reflection: take values from an unknown running application

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

I'm writing an application that searchs for Semaphore types in the fields of unknown classes in unknown application (passed by user). I made it using Reflection and it worked.

Now I want to fill up these semaphores with values, taking them from a running instance of this unknown application. So i took the class with "main" method of this unknown application, made a newInstance, and passed it when invoking the main method to start the application:

```
Class mainClass = getItSomeWhere();
Object instance = mainClass.newInstance();
Method mainMethod = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
mainMethod.invoke(instance, new Object[]{args});
```

and it worked fine.

Now, how can I get the semaphore values, taking them from the classes of this running application, when I only have an instance of the main class?

Many thanks for the answers.

Comment: You even do not have to create instance. Main method is static, so you can invoke it without instance passing null instead.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "semaphore"? Synchronized blocks?

Comment: I know i can pass null, but i need an instance that let me get values. With Semaphore i mean java.util.concurrent.Semaphore class

Comment: Now I understand what you told me about instance, you mean that main method doesn't change anything in istance. So how can I get Semaphore values in other classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexR:

I know it's a little bit incomprensible, i'll try to explain:

If the mainClass of an application is made like this:

```
public class MainClass{

       public static void main(String [] args){
                    new Gui();
       }
}
```

and you start main method by Reflection, you are not able to take the field values of Gui, nor the instances of the classes that Gui has etc.

You understand the problem?

---

EDIT:
AlexR, thank you to let me know BCEL from Jacarta, it helped me to solve the problem!

Learning how to use it, I edited all the application class files where there is a `new Semaphore();` line, and I replaced it with a custom made Semaphore extended class that let me obtain the value, passing it to an observer object!

Many thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, semaphore is just a class as all other classes. If you mean class level instances of type semaphore it is simple (exactly as you deal with class level variables of other types):

```
Class clazz = ...
for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (f.getType().equals(Semaphore.class)) {
       // do what you want here.
    }
}
```

But if you wish to deal with variables defined into methods you have to use one of byte code engineering libraries (e.g. BCL from Jakarta).

BTW your really should not create instance of class that contains your main method:

- you do not know which constructor to call and with which parameters.
- Class may be abstract, so you cannot instantiate it at all.

Comment: Thank you for telling me how to take fields from methods, it will be really useful too! But it's not my problem now. I just took semaphores from fields in the classes. All what I know is how i can get values for the fields using a running instance of the running "client" (means unknown, chosen by user) application.

Comment: `field.get(instance)` returns you the value of field of specific instance.

Comment: I have the instance for the mainclass only, i can't use it for fields of other classes

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand you. If you have instance you can say instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields(). Then iterate over the fields and say field.get(instance).